# how to read specific attribute of an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object in which i want to read only id.

i am trying to read the object using this code.

```
var d = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        arr.push(d['maps'][i].age);
        }
```

but it is giving me error

**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**

complete html code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> </title>
     <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
     <script src="js/test.json"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="myDiv"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
  <script>
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT CODE GOES HERE -->
    var arr = [];
    var d = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        arr.push(d['maps'][i].age);
        }

    console.log(arr)    
    var trace1 = {
  x: arr, 
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17], 
  type: 'scatter'
};
var trace2 = {
  x: arr, 
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9], 
  type: 'scatter'
};
var data = [trace1, trace2];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

below is my object definition:

```
data =   {
        "maps": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "iscategorical": "0"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "iscategorical": "0"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "iscategorical": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
```

whats wrong with the object ? or my code?

Comment: It means `data` is not containing your JSON file. A common cause for this is that `data` is undefined.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 When trying to replicate that, it would show position 0 if the variable is undefined.  I suspect there's something wrong with how his file is retrieved

Comment: In other words, you have to load the JSON file first and store the result in your data variable :)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 i assign this json file to  data in my json file but still same error

Comment: @billal I was unable to replicate your problem.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 this is local json file

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Hmm, can’t really tell what’s actually happening without seeing the content of `data`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫  let me add complete HTML and json file

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 now check . i added complete code.

Comment: @billal Why are you trying to parse an object?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 data is an object literal.  He's trying to parse something that's already an object.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 So this question has nothing to do with the JSON format then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that you are showing us is already parsed that is why the JSON.parse method doesn't work and throws error, also there is no age key value pair in the elements in the maps collection, that's why I'm using the id property in the snippet

```js
let initialData = {
    "maps": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        }
    ]
}

let jsonData = JSON.stringify(initialData)
let parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonData)

console.log(parsedJson)


let arrHolder = []

var d = JSON.parse(jsonData);
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        arrHolder.push(d['maps'][i].id);
        }

console.log(arrHolder)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the below example, I was unable to replicate your problem.  *I suspect* your local file is missing starting/ending quotes causing issues for the parser.

Edit: Your actual problem appears to be trying to parse an object (`data`) with `JSON.parse()`.  `JSON.parse()` expects a string.  You already have a valid object.

```
var data = `
{
    "maps": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "iscategorical": "0"
        }
    ]
}
`;

data
> "{
>     "maps": [
>         {
>             "id": "1",
>             "iscategorical": "0"
>         },
>         {
>             "id": "2",
>             "iscategorical": "0"
>         },
>         {
>             "id": "3",
>             "iscategorical": "0"
>         }
>     ]
> }"
```

---

```
var out = JSON.parse(data);

out['maps'].map(({id}) => id);
> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at your code I notice the object has no "age" value in maps, and you loop 4 times through three items. I don't get the error you report. Look at this snippet and tell me what you think:

```js
var data = '{ "maps": [{"id": "1","iscategorical": "0"},{"id": "2", "iscategorical": "0"}, {"id": "3", "iscategorical": "0" }]}';

var arr = [];
var d = JSON.parse(data);
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    arr.push(d['maps'][i].id);
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: @Micheal i correct mistakes in my code that you figure out but still i was receiving same error . But then i use your json file and it didnt get any error... So now my question is what is wrong in my JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're pulling from a .json file, you shouldn't need to use JSON.parse() to deserialize it. This would only be used when the json data is being stored as a string.

Try your code this way:

```
var d = data;
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    arr.push(d['maps'][i].age);
}
```

You also are iterating over your for loop 4 times (Zero indexed), but only have three items in your json. This will throw an error. Instead, use the length property to determine how many times to loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    arr.push(d['maps'][i].age);
}
```

Also, there is no 'age' parameter of your json example, so that will throw an error.